# MySQL: delete and insert in one commit statement in python

Tags: python, mysql, commit

I have a very simple question: I using MySQL and Python. I want to refill my table by first deleting it's content and subsequently inserting new data. However, I don't want to have an empty table (or at least only for a very very short moment) during this process.

So, as far as I remember I can combine several SQL commands and then commit them to the database. This it is ensured that everything works as described by me. So I'm wondering if my guess is correct?

```
        conn = mysql.connector.connect( **Configuration.conn_params )
        c = conn.cursor()

        sql = """DELETE FROM mytable;"""
        c.execute( sql )

        sql = """INSERT INTO mytable
                    ( col1, col2, col3 )
                 VALUES
                     ( val1, val2, val3);"""

        c.execute( sql )
        conn.commit() #run the deletion and insertion of table data "simultaneously"
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Use `TRUNCATE`, it's faster as it doesn't delete row-by-row;

Comment: @BartFriederichs: `TRUNCATE` causes implicit commit.

Comment: @toom: Your "guess" looks good to me, provided you don't override the default (false) value of the `autocommit` connection argument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: So for how long would the table be emtpy then, approximatly?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to also caveat that `mytable` must use a transactional storage engine (e.g. InnoDB) for this to work.  From the perspective of any other session, the operations will be performed atomically (as one) - there will be no instant in which they can access the empty table before the new values have been inserted.

Comment: Perfect, my table uses indeed InnoDB. If you want to you can give a full answer to my question which I will in turn accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that:

1. `mytable` uses a transactional storage engine (e.g. InnoDB); and
2. you do not override the default (false) value of the `autocommit` connection argument

then, from the perspective of any other database session, the two operations will be performed *atomically* (as one): there will be no instant in which they see an intermediate state in the database (i.e. where the records have been deleted, but the new ones have not yet been inserted).